# MapStruct dependency scope in a Maven project

Tags: java, maven, scope, mapstruct, maven-dependency

[MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org/) generates code at compile-time and [it should not require any runtime dependencies](https://mapstruct.org/faq/#How-is-MapStruct-different-from-other-bean-mapping-tools):

> **How is MapStruct different from other bean mapping tools?**
>
> Unlike most other bean mapping tools, MapStruct doesn’t work at runtime but is a compile-time code generator.
>
> Generating mapping code at build time has many advantages:
>
> - Excellent performance, as no reflection or byte code generation at runtime is needed; the generated code contains plain method invocations, just as if the mapper was hand-written
> - No runtime dependencies, making MapStruct a great solution for Android applications

Which [dependency scope](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#dependency-scope) should be used in a Maven project? Should MapStruct be included as a **provided** dependency?

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
        <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think it depends on the component model. For `spring`, `cdi` and `jsr330`, I think you don't need anything from MapStruct anymore after the code generation. For `default` you need to use `Mappers` so you would definitely need MapStruct. If you're not using `default` I'd just try it as provided and see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `org.mapstruct:mapstruct` dependency contains the needed annotations to signal the `org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor` what to do.

It also contains the `Mappers` factory that is used when using the default component model. Therefore, the scope of `org.mapstruct:mapstruct` depends on the component model that you are using:

## Default component model

If you are using this component model then you need `org.mapstruct:mapstruct` during runtime if you are using `Mappers` or if you have dependencies between different mappers.

In theory you can use the default component model and instantiate your own mappers. However, dependencies between mappers are still going to use `Mappers`, unless you have instantiated your mapper in `MyMapper.INSTANCE` somehow already, then MapStruct will use `MyMapper.INSTANCE` to get the instance of the `MyMapper`. This would mean that you can still use the same scope as the other component models (see below for more information)

## Other component model (spring, jsr330, cdi, etc.)

In this case you do not need `org.mapstruct:mapstruct` during runtime and you can use `<optional>true</optional>` with `<scope>provided</scope>`.

With Gradle this would be `compileOnly` dependency.

Note: Be careful when using Spring Boot and `<scope>provided</scope>` the Spring Boot maven plugin will still include the `org.mapstruct:mapstruct` dependency in the final provided jar. You'll need to ignore it by configuring the Spring Boot Maven plugin.